# Mathematical Logic Inference theory

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

Show that $(L \lor m)$ logically follows from:

- $p\land q\land r$
- $(q\leftrightarrow r) \to (L \lor m)$

how to solve this using inference theory?
i could get till here,

1. p,q,r --- (rule p)
2. (q → r) ∧ (r → q) → (L ∨ m) ---(rule p)
3. (q → r),(r → q) → (L ∨ m)

what to do after this.. i got stuck here..

Comment: Can you post the exact rules you are supposed to work with?  For example, what is exactly your 'rule p'? There are *many* of these formal proof systems, but they all have slightly different sets of rules. We can't really help you if you don't let us know what rules you have to work with. Also, please use Mathjax to format your formulas.  I just formatted the first few formulas  so you see how this works ... can you please do the others? Thanks!

Comment: 1. Rule p is nothing but premises 
2.Law of detachment 
p
p→Q  result is Q

3.transitive rule ie. If p→Q  and Q→r  then p→r  
4.Contrapositive rule:
p→Q  
    ~Q  result is  ~p

Answer (score 1):

*Hint*

From $p \land q \land r$ derive $q$ and $r$ separately using [Simplification rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_elimination).

From $q$ derive $\lnot r \lor q$ by [Addition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunction_introduction) and transform it into the equivalent $(r \to q)$.

In the same way, from $r$ derive $(q \to r)$.

Then use [Conjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_introduction) to get $(r \to q) \land (q \to r)$ followed by [Biconditional introduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biconditional_introduction) to get :

> $(q \leftrightarrow r)$.